# will i damage this toy motor by running it on a higher voltage?

Tags: voltage, motor, mains

I have a hand held shaver that is chargeable. the socket plug for the device says

```
02A250V-
```

and the green battery inside the device looks like this:

[image]

and the back of the board:

[image]

I have an old mobile charger that outputs 5.0v

[image]

In the first image there are two red cables +- can I connect the mobile charger directly to the motor and just remove the whole board/charger or will this make the motor run at 5x the speed, over heat it or damage my friends face?

If it will work fine; the mobile charger cable is colored with white stripes on one of its cable's tubes (how do i tell which one is positive?)

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the rest of your question, but as for "which is positive", I always have to measure it.  There *might* be a standard, but these things are so cheaply made that I wouldn't trust it.

Comment: Okay, I reread and I think you're asking if it's okay to run a 1.2V motor on a 5V, current-limited supply.  Answering now...

Comment: "You'll put your eye out"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if it's okay to run a 1.2V motor on a 5V current-limited supply, I think it'll probably work for a while (really fast!!!) and then not work at all.  You might get a few shaves out of it, it probably won't burn anyone (not enough juice available from that supply), but a wire or solder joint may melt inside the motor and then it's done.

As for the polarity (assuming you want to continue this experiment or use this info elsewhere), I don't bother memorizing that.  I always measure it with a voltmeter.  That tells me the polarity, *and* verifies the correct voltage.

Comment: I'm guessing the brushes burn out or melt first, unless the phone charger lets its smoke out...

Comment: I'd be really surprised if the phone charger died.  Small DC supplies like that tend to be pretty bulletproof, either by using someone else's dirt cheap chip/circuit that refuses to blow itself up, or by using such limiting parts that it can barely make the stated specs.  Either way, those things seem to bounce back from just about anything except plugging their outputs across a wall socket.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't. Or at least not without a proper design. DC motors' speed are directly proportional to their voltage. So you should expect a motor running 4 times faster. The higher voltage may break the isolation of the internal circuit of the motor making a short and so burning it. But hopeful you have a lot of options to drop your voltage to the 1.2V specified. At this current (600mA) you can use a linear regulator (not the most energy efficient solution) like the LM317, which is very easy to use. Or you can also try some diodes and resistances.